# Why await for async method in the middle of a method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I found this example using async/await stuff in a book. Could please someone tell me what's the benefit of awaiting for async methods like in the example below?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM People", connection);
  await connection.OpenAsync();
  SqlDataReader dataReader = **await** command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
  while (**await** dataReader.ReadAsync())
  {
    string formatStringWithMiddleName = "Person ({0}) is named {1} {2} {3}";
    string formatStringWithoutMiddleName = "Person ({0}) is named {1} {3}";
    if ((dataReader["middlename"] == null))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(formatStringWithoutMiddleName,
      dataReader["id"],
      dataReader["firstname"],
      dataReader["lastname"]);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine(formatStringWithMiddleName,
      dataReader["id"],
      dataReader["firstname"],
      dataReader["middlename"],
      dataReader["lastname"]);
    }
  }
  dataReader.Close();
  }
}
```

I just can't wrap my head around this. The way I understand, await blocks until the method called (in this case, ExecuteReaderAsync and ReadAsync) returns. What's the point of calling an async method and blocking right away in the middle of the code, without actually doing anything between the call to the async method and the point when the result is returned to the caller?
How is it faster or more efficient than simply doing this?

....

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
      while (dataReader.Read())
      {
           .....
```

Comment: by waiting for the async method to finish, they are able to treat async code like synchronous code.  This has been a problem in software development for a long time, and the way the author chose to deal with it is one of many.  It's not my preferred way, but this example may also be very old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The way I understand, await blocks until the method called (in this case, ExecuteReaderAsync and ReadAsync) returns.

No; `await` will *pause* the method and *return* to the caller. Thus, it does *not* block the calling thread for the duration of the `ReadAsync` operation.

Conceptually, it's the difference between *synchronous* and *serial*. Synchronous means blocking: the method call stops the thread until the `Read` completes. Serial means one at a time: the method will pause execution until the `ReadAsync` completes. So, the common `await *Async()` pattern is serial, but in an asynchronous way, not a synchronous way.

For more information about `async` and `await`, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post.

Comment: Btw am I the only one who thinks that "await" contextual keyword was a bad choice? I can't think of a better variant though.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov: I have a blog post which is a kind of [unofficial Q&A on why the `async` and `await` keywords were designed the way they were](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html).

Comment: Interesting post, thank you. Although it mostly describes linguistic reasoning behind "await", not the philological reason why "await" was chosen instead of, for example, "leave" or "digress from" (while keeping the semantics).

Comment: Ah. Yes, there was some discussion around that, and a few variants were considered. I don't even remember what they were, now.

Answer (score 0):

This temporarily blocks your method but keeps the UI-thread responding. Internally C# rewrites the method. The part after `await` is converted to a kind callback method (well not really, but you can imagine it was). The method returns immediately at the `await` and resumes where it has left off, when the async operation finishes.